# SQLite multiple columns update syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to execute this SQL query using SQLiteDatabase.execSQL method as below:

```
String sql="UPDATE vehicle SET (name,haltpattern,type1) = ( SELECT name,haltpattern,type1 FROM v_vehicle WHERE vehicle.code = v_vehicle.code) WHERE vehicle.code IN  ( SELECT vehicle.code FROM vehicle);"
db.execSQL(sql);
```

I am getting below error: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE vehicle SET (name,haltpattern,type1) = ( SELECT name,haltpattern,type1 FROM v_vehicle WHERE vehicle.code = v_vehicle.code) WHERE vehicle.code IN  ( SELECT vehicle.code FROM vehicle);

When I run the same SQL using SQLiteStudio, it works fine.
Please help

Thanks
Tarun

Comment: *When I run the same SQL using SQLiteStudio, it works fine* **no** it does not.

Comment: @forpas In my SQLiteStudio this query works fine. Anyways can you tell me what is wrong here as per SQLite DB.

Comment: What version of sqlite are you using in android?

Comment: Row value support was added in 3.15.0. Trying to use them in an older version would cause syntax errors.

Comment: Also, what is that WHERE clause trying to do? `UPDATE vehicle SET ... WHERE vehiicle.code IN (SELECT vehicle.code FROM vehicle) is going to be true for every row.

Comment: @Shawn If row value support is not present then what do I use. Do you know the syntax. And yes the outer WHERE clause is used as a correlated update query so that non-joined records are not set to null

Comment: If you're using an old version, you'd have to update each column individually. `UPDATE blah SET foo = 1, bar = 2`. And again, that where clause will match every single row, because you're asking if the current row being updated exists in the table being updated, which it obviously does.

Comment: Thanks, @Shawn. Updating individual columns has done it. Thanks a lot for your help. Please post an answer so that I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Shawn("If you're using an old version, you'd have to update each column individually. UPDATE blah SET foo = 1, bar = 2."), My SQLite version did not support multiple columns update hence I updated the columns individually.

Answer (score 0):

Do SQLiteStudio have something like an "autocorrect" function?

Im not sure but maby it's the space between "(" and "Select":
UPDATE vehicle SET (name,haltpattern,type1) = **( S**ELECT name,haltpattern,type1 FROM v_vehicle WHERE vehicle.code = v_vehicle.code) WHERE vehicle.code IN ( SELECT vehicle.code FROM vehicle);

Comment: It doesn't matter if there's whitespace there or not.